# How to take into account the existing ids in unique rule in laravel excel upload?

Tags: php, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

```
<?php

    namespace App\Imports;
    use App\Models\Customer;
    use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
    
    class CustomerImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation
    {
        public $timestamps = false;
       
    
        public function collection(Collection $rows)
        {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                
                Customer::create([
                    'name'     => $row['name'],
               
                ]);
                 
            }
        }
    
        public function rules(): array
        {
            return [
                'name'      => [
                    'required',
                    'max:50',
                    'unique:customers,name',
                ],
               
            
            ];
        }
    }
```

My Controller Code is as follows:

```
    public function uploadFile(Request $request)
    {
            $request->validate(
                ['file' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:txt,csv']],
                ['file.required' => 'Please upload the file']
            );
            try {
                Excel::import(new CustomerImport(), $request->file('file'));
            } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
                $failures = $e->failures();
                return redirect()
                    ->route('customers.upload')
                    ->withErrors($failures);
            }
            return redirect()
                ->route('customers.index')
                ->with('success', __('customers.message_uploaded'));
        }
```

I create a customer and then want to change its name. How would I do that? I cannot upload the same name. Because it would not be unique. So I need to take into account the id when trying the uniqueness. I am not sure exactly how to do that during validation. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you are not storing the selection in any way, so after the page refresh there is not way for the server to know to render the result that was accomplished via Javascript manipulation.

Store the change in a cookie, session or local storage, then on render, retrieve the data.